# Nested List Operations By Index

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a nested list, each element within the nested list is a group of 4.  I want to perform arithmetic on each element in the list but am unsure how to access them.

```
my_nested_list = [[1, 0, 0, 3], [7, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 3]]

for i in my_nested_list:
    for num in i:
        if num[0] == 7:      
            num[1] = num[1] * num[1]
```

How could I square the second number of the nested list if the first number of the nested list == 7?  I thought the code I have above would work but it is not.  Any ideas?

The output I am expecting is for the 2 to become 4.

```
my_nested_list = [[1, 0, 0, 3], [7, 4, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: `my_listed_list` is a list of lists of ints. You have `for i in my_nested_list`, so `i` is a list of ints. You have `for num in i`, so `num` is an int. What is `num[0]` supposed to be?

Comment: just updated the output I am expecting.

Comment: @oppressionslayer Three are wrong, one replaces the outer loop with an index-loop, and one appallingly pops+inserts. student's answer is the only one not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through list in nested list for which you may only need to check first element instead of iterating inner list. May be you could try following:

```
my_nested_list = [[1, 0, 0, 3], [7, 2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 3]]

for num in my_nested_list:
    if num[0] == 7: # for each list only need to compare first element
        num[1] = num[1] * num[1]
print(my_nested_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 3], [7, 4, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score -3):

```py
my_nested_list = [[1, 0, 0, 3], [7, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 3]]

for i in my_nested_list:
  for j in 3: # you have 3 lists
    if my_nested_list[j][i] == 1:
      my_nested_list[j][i+1]**2
```